# Android: How to use Japanese Unihan glyphs?

Tags: android, unicode, cjk

I'm developing an app to teach Japanese. The problem is, the default font the system uses is using the Chinese variants of the characters, not the Japanese variants. For example, 漢 looks slightly different in Chinese fonts than in Japanese fonts even though it's the same Unicode codepoint. How can I specify that my app should use a Japanese font and not a Chinese one?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503133/japanese-characters-looking-like-chinese-on-android

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't find a better solution you might just use your own .ttf or .otf files, place them in /assets/fonts and load them using [createFromAsset()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#createFromAsset%28android.content.res.AssetManager,%20java.lang.String%29)