# How to embed a custom font to Android app (WebView)

Tags: android, sqlite, fonts, webview

I want to embed a custom font into my android app. I don't use TextView so such tutorials as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424165/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-android-application) (How to use custom font with TextView) do not help.

In my case, the content is taken from the SQLite database and shown on the screen using WebView. I don't either use bundled HTML files so [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344080/how-to-use-custom-font-with-webview) (How to use custom font with WebView) does not solve my problem, either.

FIY, here is my code:

```
public void initWebview()
{
    WebSettings settings = wvContent.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    setContentView(R.layout.content);
    wvContent = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvContent);
    wvContent.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(250, 250, 250, 250));
    wvContent.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);  
    wvContent.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);       
    wvContent.setInitialScale(100); 
    wvContent.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()

    {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            if (pd != null)
            {
                pd.dismiss();
                pd = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            Log.i(CONTENT_TAG,"WebView link clicked; url = " + url);
            try
            {
                String arrUrlPart[] = url.split("://");

                if (arrUrlPart[0].equals("entry"))
                {
                    String content = getContentByWord(arrUrlPart[1]);
                    showContent(content);
                }
                else if (arrUrlPart[0].equals("http"))
                {
                     try {                             
                         startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));                              
                     } catch (Exception ex) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                         ex.printStackTrace();
                     }                      
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

The font stored in **assets/fonts** seems to be embedded into the app, and my questions are:

1. **How can I programmatically do to "force" my app to use this font?**
2. **Are there any solutions to my problem?**

Thank you very much.

Comment: Some guidance here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503133/japanese-characters-looking-like-chinese-on-android

Comment: Thanks, but not my case.

Answer (score 9):

From the comments in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7395170/16725) reply, a possible solution seems to be to use `loadDataWithBaseURL` while providing the assets folder as the base url, i.e.

> LoadData() does not work, but
>   webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",... works fine.
>   Then also font file reference as "/fonts/MyFont.otf" should work. –
>   JaakL Dec 1 '11 at 16:59

I assume bundling your *font* is not a problem, right?

**[Edit]** To clarify my answer, I've composed a little example. In the code below, I've put the `Quicksand_Dash.otf` in *assets/fonts*, and `twitter_logo.png` straight into *assets*. The HTML is simply a string constant, but you'd retrieve it from your SQLLite database. The essence is really just to use `loadDataWithBaseURL()`....

```
package oh.jolly.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebviewTestActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", PAGE_HTML, "text/html", "UTF-8", "null" );
    }

    private final static String PAGE_HTML =
        "<html>\n" +
        "  <style type=\"text/css\"> \n" + 
        "   @font-face { \n" + 
        "       font-family: MyFont; \n" + 
        "       src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/Quicksand_Dash.otf\") \n" + 
        "   } \n" + 
        "   body { \n" + 
        "       font-family: MyFont; \n" + 
        "       font-size: medium; \n" + 
        "       text-align: justify; \n" + 
        "   } \n" + 
        "  </style> \n" + 
        "  <body>\n" + 
        "    I've got a sinking feeling...<br>\n" + 
        "    <img src=\"file:///android_asset/twitter_logo.png\" />\n" + 
        "  </body>\n" + 
        "</html>";


}
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand your point, but I have tried [this tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android/7395170#7395170) and it works only when text strings requiring the embedded font are between `<body>...</body>` inside HTML files stored in **assets**. However in my case, data is from the SQLite database. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. That's why I (and the quoted comment) suggest you use loadDataWithBaseURL (as opposed to loadURL in that tutorial). You still provide the asset url for the fonts, but the html comes from the SQL database.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Paul. But I can't adapt your example to my code. I guess there is something incompatible on my side. That's why it always show unfixed errors in Eclipse. I'm still trying hard now.

Comment: Well, in the end I could get it run but not as what I expected. My app content from its SQLite database is not loaded, but just the sentence **I've got a sinking feeling...** and a logo instead.

Comment: Yes, loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/" is the solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You saved my ass :p
+9999

Answer (score 0):

Please check below links ... i think its useful

[How to change font face of Webview in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android)

[How to use custom font with WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344080/how-to-use-custom-font-with-webview)

Set your custom font on html header and set your content in html body. so all content display as per your embed font in webview...

Comment: Many thanks, I have previously tried those but as I said I don't used bundled HTML file so they don't help.

Comment: you are runtime generate string in which html body and your sqlite content ... not required html file creation.